# Can you customize the avatar of a message posted to Teams by the Incoming Webhook connector?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

We're using the Incoming Webhook connector to send alerts to a Teams channel. I do a similar thing for Slack, where I can change the identity (i.e. name and avatar) of the "person" posting the message, based on attributes of the JSON payload. However, I've had trouble finding full documentation of the available payload attributes used for this connector, and the examples I've seen are very basic, using only payload attributes that define the title and message of the resulting card.

So is there an authoritative document out there that defines all the available payload attributes for the Incoming Webhook connector? And do the available attributes allow for customizing the name and avatar/icon of the simulated user who is posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently incoming webhooks support the Office 365 Connector Card format (aka actionable message card format). The specification is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference.

It does not support the ability to change the name and avatar posting the message though, and I'm not sure we ever will because it could be misused for a phishing attack.

A longstanding request is to support Adaptive Cards over incoming webhooks though, and we hope to get to that soon.